# Emacs Python-mode throws a format-message error

Tags: emacs, emacs24

I am using Ubuntu 15.10 and Emacs 24. but recently when i open a Python
source file in Emacs or create a new one, i get an error:

> symbol's function definition is void: format-message
>
> The file is opened as a Fundamental.

edit: this error only happens if i use my custom `.emacs` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the question in some IRC group's and came up with an answer... it seemed that elpa Python.el package, tries to load a file that is not python and is C++...

I just had to delete the file and it worked again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why that's failing, but perhaps we can fix this problem by writing our own `format-message`. Try putting this in your `.emacs`:

```
(defun format-message (s &rest args)
  (message (apply 'format s args)))
```